# Change npm start to another command

Tags: node.js, npm

In NodeJS, sometimes I want to change the **npm start** to another command, for example like **ns**, how can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Look up bash aliases. What shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using Window CMD, terminal in VS Code

Comment: I've tried the "echo $SHELL" command, it shows nothing. I have the "bash_profile" and it has the path attribute.
    "path": [
      "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
      "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
     ]
I'm still don't understand your idea, can you describe it in more specification?

Comment: Did my answer below work out for you?

Comment: I didn't find any alias in the window OS bash. It's not work

Comment: Can you try typing my answer into your terminal, pressing enter, typing ns, press enter, and share the result? Not sure what you mean that you can’t “find” alias. You can also try “man alias”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash “alias” for this.

Add the following to your bash_profile (or equivalent file):

`alias ns=“npm start”`